# Exit a program by pressing the key q

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I have wrote a shell script in which I would like to include the functionality to exit the program by pressing the <kbd>q</kbd> key. Can I do that?

Here is what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Press Q to exit \t\t:\c"
read input 
if [[ $input = "q" ]] || [[ $input = "Q" ]] 
    then exit 1 
else 
    echo "Invalid Input." 
fi
```

Comment: There's no general way to do that. If you show us your script we can probably tell you what you can achieve and how?

Comment: It depends what it does but I don't see any benefit in doing that.  Why not simply use CTRL-C while you're at it?

Comment: You could look at using `stty intr q` near the top of the script to "remap" CTRL-C to q.  This has the disadvantage that CTRL-C will no longer do anything...  If you decide this is an accaeptable approach, you will want to `trap` the SIGINT such that you can reset the mapping using `stty intr ^c`

Comment: Thanks Henrik & Julie for your prompt response. Here is my script but it exits if I've entered anyother key otherthan 'q' saying invalid input. I would like to loop the program such that it should again prompt for the input without exiting.

#!/bin/ksh
echo "Press Q to exit \t\t:\c"
read input
if [[ $input = "q" ]] || [[ $input = "Q" ]]
then
 exit 1
else
echo "Invalid Input."
fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `while read input`, but due to we want to avoid repeat the `echo -en "Press Q to exit \t\t: "` statement twice, so we better off to use `while true` instead (a [do while](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60099/64403) variant):

```
xiaobai:tmp $ cat hello.sh 
#!/bin/ksh
while true; do
    echo -en "Press Q to exit \t\t: "
    read input
    if [[ $input = "q" ]] || [[ $input = "Q" ]] 
        then break 
    else 
        echo "Invalid Input."
    fi
done
xiaobai:tmp $ ./hello.sh 
Press Q to exit                 : apple
Invalid Input.
Press Q to exit                 : q
xiaobai:tmp $
```